# Google Colab Something went wrong

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I try to connect google colab with my account I am having this error message:
Something went wrong
Sorry, something went wrong there. Try again.

With another account I can connect.

[image: error image]

Comment: A few clarifying questions: Are you executing some code which generates this prompt? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem? Have you enabled [advanced account protection](https://landing.google.com/advancedprotection/) for your account?

Answer (score 0):

this is temporarly and

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

won't work for a while but you can do it by this way:
[1.go to files 2.mount the drive by clicking on the Drive icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix1WJ.jpg)
[then you can see the drive folder after a while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzcGZ.jpg)

the picture: